# llamaIndex-semantic-chunking- problem-pdf-file

Tags: large-language-model, llama-index, openaiembeddings, text-chunking

#all the necessary
pip install llama-index-embeddings-openai
pip install -U llama-index-readers-file
reader = SimpleDirectoryReader(
input_files=["ai.pdf"]
)

```
docs = reader.load_data()
print(f"Loaded {len(docs)} docs")
from llama_index.core.node_parser import (
    SentenceSplitter,
    SemanticSplitterNodeParser,
)
from llama_index.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbedding
```

#semantic splitter is used here
import os

```
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "key"
embed_model = OpenAIEmbedding()
splitter = SemanticSplitterNodeParser(
    buffer_size=1, breakpoint_percentile_threshold=95, embed_model=embed_model
)
```

## also baseline splitter

```
base_splitter = SentenceSplitter(chunk_size=512)
```

```
nodes = splitter.get_nodes_from_documents(docs)
print(nodes[5])
```

### the below line i want to  assess

```
for i, chunk in enumerate(nodes): 
    print(f"CHUNK {i+1}: ", chunk)// i got the chunks here
```

so here i have been working with llamaindex semantic chunker. i was able to produce the chunks of whole pdf file but if i have to get the chunks of specific page like say page no. of 5 of file how do i do it.?is there special way i have to treat pdf file?

i tried-
for i, chunk in enumerate(nodes[4]):
print(f"CHUNK {i+1}: ", chunk)
but it produces-
metadata about it
like file name,embeddings id etc with different different chunk name.
chunk1:('id','3235632354')
chunk2:('embedding,'None')
etc.`